# Multiple sheets not generating when executed report on JRS but same works fine on local Studio application

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, jasperserver

I'm using iReport 5.6.0 to design a report and deploy it to Product Version: 7.1.0
Build: 20180504_1307.

I want to use JasperReports Server to export excel report with multiple sheet (one page per sheet). When I export excel report with iReport, I have a multiple sheet excel but with JasperReports Server, I don't.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.names.all" value="Report1/Report2/../summary"/>
```

This is required and is present in my code.

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
```